# Python3 string representation

Tags: python-3.x

In Python2 one could:

```
>>> struct.pack(">f", 125.4)
>>> 'B\xfa\xcc\xcd'
```

How can I get the same string in Python3? I've tried different encodings, but can get it exactly.

Comment: Don't you want to just delete leading zeros?
Python3 gives **b"\x00\x00\x00\x00\xcd\xcc\xfa8"**

Comment: I don't know what you entered as a pack format, but I don't think it is what I show above. But even still, you are showing bytes, and I want a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the correct string by decoding the bytes with the 'latin1' codec. It doesn't look the same in the Python3 console as it does in the Python2 console, but it was interpreted the same by the program.

Python2:

```
>>> struct.pack(">f", 125.4)
'B\xfa\xcc\xcd'
```

Python3:

```
>>> b = struct.pack(">f", 125.4)
>>> b.decode("latin1")
<something that cannot be pasted>
```